# Reading all json files in a directory

Tags: python, json, directory

I have multiple (400) json files containing a dict in a directory that I want to read and append to a list. I've tried looping over all the files in the directory like this:

```
path_to_jsonfiles = 'TripAdvisorHotels'
alldicts = []
for file in os.listdir(path_to_jsonfiles):
    with open(file,'r') as fi:
        dict = json.load(fi)
alldicts.append(dict)
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

However, when I look at the files in the directory, it gives me all the right files.

```
for file in os.listdir(path_to_jsonfiles):
    print(file)
```

Just opening one of them with the file name works as well.

```
with open('AWEO-q_GiWls5-O-PzbM.json','r') as fi:
    data = json.load(fi)
```

Were in the loop is it going wrong?

Comment: Maybe try adding a print statement to your loop to see which file specifically is causing the error.

Comment: You need to give full file path

Comment: It is not necessary to write in full file path as in the last piece of code, it works fine.

Comment: Yes sorry forgot to include the path to the directory in my code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code has two errors:

1.`file` is only the file name. You have to write full filepath (including its folder).

2.You have to use `append` inside the loop.

To sum up, this should work:

```
alldicts = []
for file in os.listdir(path_to_jsonfiles):
    full_filename = "%s/%s" % (path_to_jsonfiles, file)
    with open(full_filename,'r') as fi:
        dict = json.load(fi)
        alldicts.append(dict)
```

Comment: Yes sorry I see I've pasted the indents wrong for the appending bit. But the full filepath worked like a charm! Can you explain to me what `"%s/%s" %` does?

Comment: @Lisadk thats called string formatting. Say, you want to place a variable inside a string. Instead of doing it like `full_filename = path_to_jsonfiles + "/" + file`, you can assign placeholders inside string using `%s` for strings, `%d` for integers etc. After you declare your string structure like `"%s/%s"`, simply put a `%` and assign variables in order.